# Is it possible to wrap json in json field like a string?

Tags: json

I have a json like this:

json1 :

```
{  
    "field1": 111111,
    "field2": "someValue"
}
```

How can I wrap it in "requestBody" field into json2 like a string?

json2 :

```
{  
    "requestBody": json1  
}
```

Something like this:

```
{  
    "requestBody": "{"field1": 111111,"field2": "someValue"}"
}
```

Comment: use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Why would you want a full JSON object in a JSON field?

Comment: It's the same as serialzing any other string. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

JSON-encoded stuff is just a string. If you want to embed json-in-json, then the "inner" json has to be encoded into json itself.

e.g.

```
$inner = {"foo":"bar"}
$outer = {"container":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"}
```

Now the inner json isn't json anymore. It's just a string that happens to kinda/sorta look like JSON.

Comment: To convert json to string: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

Answer (score 8):

It won't be pretty, but if you base64 encode the JSON payload, you can be sure it won't be parsed unexpectedly.

How to base64 encode using Javascript:
http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

```
{  
    "requestBody": "eyJmaWVsZDEiOiAxMTExMTEsImZpZWxkMiI6ICJzb21lVmFsdWUifQ=="
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As Marc B noted, inner quotes must be escaped.

`{"requestBody":"{\"field1\":111111,\"field2\":\"someValue\"}"}`

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cheoc1zj/

Answer (score -3):

Escaping double quoted strings is ugly. Why not use single quoted strings in the embedded JSON? For example:

```
{
    "container":"{'foo':'bar'}"
}
```

Comment: because that wouldn't be JSON.