Endpoint payload contains escaped double quotes
I'm calling several endpoints in VBA (Excel) using the following code:
req.Open "GET", url, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
req.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
req.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & sessionId
req.send

One of these endpoints will always escape the double quotes in the returned string.
When req.responseText is output, all double quotes look like this \". This endpoint doesn't do this in any other context such as Postman, PHP or cURL.
Edit #1
Example response, notice escaped double quotes. I only get this from one endpoint and cannot replicate in Postman, PHP or cURL.
[[{\"PK__REVFLAGID\":null,\"grp\":\"Implementation Tracking\",\"flag\":\"Green\",\"FLAG_DESCRIPTION\":null}]]

Edit #2
Public req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60


There's nothing in the fact you're using VBA which I can see would cause that behavior, and without any knowledge of what endpoint you're calling it's difficult to offer any suggestions.   The only thing I could guess if that what you're getting back is actually valid JSON, but the bulk of it is JSON encoded in the value of one of the top-level properties. See for example:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570795/478884   If you show us an example responseText value things might be clearer.

@timwilliams added a snippet of returned JSON. And I agree, doesn't make sense.

Can't you just use Replace(reg.responseText, "\", "") and contiune with parsing?

What exactly is req in your code?

One thing worth noting maybe is that since this is a GET and there's no request body content, you don't need the Content-type header.  Have you tried omitting that?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693884/478884

@TimWilliams, if you are asking me what the reg is, it is : Set reg = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

@timwilliams I added definition of req. I'll also check the link you mention.

@haluk that's what I'm doing now, but wanted to see if I was missing something.

Not sure I have anything else to suggest - this maybe seems like something to be worked out with the endpoint provider?

@timwilliams provider is adamant it's not at their end since they tested and weren't able to replicate on other platforms/mechanisms (ex. Postman, cURL, etc.). I guess I'll keep my implementation with Replace and call it a day.
